# load an external dataset using javascript prefetch

Tags: javascript, datalist, prefetch

Hi I'm building an autocomplete function for a searchbox in my website. 
I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $terms = [ "aggretatibacter aphrophilus", "abiotrophia defectiva", "aerococcus viridans", "aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans", "aeromonas hydrophila", "aerococcus urinae", "actinobacillus ureae", "achromobacter xylosoxidans", "capnocytophaga gingivalis", "acinetobacter baumannii", "streptococcus pyogenes" ].sort(),
$return = [];

function strInArray(str, strArray) {
for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
if (strArray[j].match(str) && $return.length < 5) {
  var $h = strArray[j].replace(str, '<strong>'+str+'</strong>');
  $return.push('<li class="prediction-item"><span class="prediction-text">' + $h + '</span></li>');
}
}
}

function nextItem(kp) {
  if ( $('.focus').length > 0 ) {
var $next = $('.focus').next(),
    $prev = $('.focus').prev();
}

if ( kp == 38 ) { // Up

if ( $('.focus').is(':first-child') ) {
  $prev = $('.prediction-item:last-child');
}

$('.prediction-item').removeClass('focus');
$prev.addClass('focus');

} else if ( kp == 40 ) { // Down

if ( $('.focus').is(':last-child') ) {
  $next = $('.prediction-item:first-child');
}

$('.prediction-item').removeClass('focus');
$next.addClass('focus');
}
}

$(function(){  
  $('#s').keydown(function(e){
$key = e.keyCode;
if ( $key == 38 || $key == 40 ) {
  nextItem($key);
  return;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  var $search = $('#s').val();
  $return = [];

  strInArray($search, $terms);

  if ( $search == '' || ! $('input').val ) {
    $('.output').html('').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.output').html($return).slideDown();
  }

  $('.prediction-item').on('click', function(){
    $text = $(this).find('span').text();
    $('.output').slideUp(function(){
      $(this).html('');
    });
    $('#s').val($text);
  });

  $('.prediction-item:first-child').addClass('focus');

}, 50);
});
});

$('#s').focus(function(){
if ( $('.prediction-item').length > 0 ) {
  $('.output').slideDown();
}

$('#searchform').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $text = $('.focus').find('span').text();
  $('.output').slideUp();
  $('#s').val($text);
  $('input').blur();
  });
 });

 $('#s').blur(function(){
if ( $('.prediction-item').length > 0 ) {
  $('.output').slideUp();
}
});

});
```

I would like to load another page as a datalist instead of the:

```
   [ "aggretatibacter aphrophilus", "abiotrophia defectiva", "aerococcus viridans", "aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans", "aeromonas hydrophila", "aerococcus urinae", "actinobacillus ureae", "achromobacter xylosoxidans", "capnocytophaga gingivalis", "acinetobacter baumannii", "streptococcus pyogenes" ]
```

part

But what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome on SO! You did a good job posting sample code and a quite clear question. However, I don't see how the datalist is involved in your code. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: whoops, sorry. I must have cut it out of the rest somehow. I've edited the question post. It's directly after the document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var $terms = [ "aggretatibacter aphrophilus", ... ].sort(),
```

Can be loaded from a url using [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON( "yourUrl", function( data )
{
  var $terms = [];

  $.each( data, function( val )
  {
    terms.push( val );
  }
  );

  terms.sort();
});
```

Comment: @SaskiaWestra: Need more help?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reply. I've added your code to mine, tested it and received no errors. However, it doesnt load the names from the datalist. Do I have to install JQuery getJSON? I've JQuery-1.10.2 installed.

Comment: Your use of jQuery is fine. Are you sure the url returns a JSON formatted array? Like in the sample link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/.

Comment: well, it looks like this:
    ["Aggretatibacter aphrophilus", "Abiotrophia defectiva", "Aerococcus viridans", "Aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans", "Aeromonas hydrophila", "Aerococcus urinae", "Actinobacillus ureae", "Achromobacter xylosoxidans", "Capnocytophaga gingivalis", "Acinetobacter baumannii", "Streptococcus pyogenes"]

Comment: Replace `[` and `]` by `{` and `}`.

Comment: Any messages in the browser's console?

Comment: Yes, it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $terms is not defined.

Comment: My bad. You should pull the declaration of `terms` outside this code sample so it can be found in other method calls.

Comment: @Saskia: need more help?

Comment: Well, I still haven't been able to fix it. But that might be because of my poor javascript knowledge.